# How to translate the UIImagePickerController preview?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

When I open `UIImagePickerController()` and set `showsCameraControls = false`, the camera preview sits against the top of the screen. How do I move this preview down so it is at the same location as when `showCameraControls = true`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer whilst trawling online:

```
// Create the UIImagePickerController without camera controls
var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
imagePicker.delegate = self
imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
imagePicker.showsCameraControls = false

// Translate the camera preview down by 50px
let translate: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 50.0)
imagePicker.cameraViewTransform = translate

// Now add custom overlay
// ...
```